# Is it possible for users with less than 10k rep to access moderator tools?

Tags: discussion, privileges, 10k-tools

[Only 10k reputations holders can access the moderator tools.](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools)

My doubt is,

If a user has 10k+ reputation in Meta Stack Overflow but, less than 10k in main site (Stack Overflow) like [hims056](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/187824/hims056).

Is it possible for that type of users to get access with moderator tools on Stack Overflow?

Comment: No I can't.. :(

Comment: If the user is a mod, they get access to all tools even with 1 rep (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/160410/minitech)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is not possible to access moderator tools if you don't have 10K reputation on the same site. Even if you have 10K reputation on Meta Stack Overflow and don't have 10K on Stack Overflow, you can not access 10K tools on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6):

No, only moderators (elected or employees) can access this page regardless of reputation.

Meta SO is special in that it has its own reputation and in that respect completely separate from Stack Overflow. It is unlike any other child-meta (which don't have their own reputation, but inherit the reputation from their main site).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if they've been elected as a moderator. There's no "reasonable" rep limit to run as a moderator, and there's certainly mods with less than 10k rep.

Comment: They are not using 10K tools they are using Diamond Moderators tools. (AFAIK)

Comment: The question states moderator tools in the title...

Comment: for getting elected as a moderator, a candidate should have 3k(reasonable rep limit) minimum rep, is it so?

Comment: @hims056 Mods get access to the 10K tools as well.

Comment: @Yannis - Yeah just noticed that. I thought they can access all tools (10k + Diamond) from the same page.

Comment: @hims056 We see `/tools` exactly as 10K+ users do. The mod only tools are grouped under `/admin`.